# Using Java Card 's RandonData.getInstance

Tags: javacard

My applet crashed when I call the following line of code

```
RandomData rd = RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
```

I get the following output:

```
OffCard Installer [v3.0.2]  
    Copyright (c) 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  
    All rights reserved.  
    Use is subject to license terms.  
[ INFO: ] [Creating an instance of ClassicApplet1 with instance ID //aid/E96473AB62/DF on http://localhost:8019/cardmanager]  
[ INFO: ] "Off Card Installer validating create information"  
[ INFO: ] "Off Card Installer preparing create information"  
[ INFO: ] "Off Card Installer sending create request"  
[ INFO: ] Create failed: null  
run-client:  
run-script:  
Invoking apdutool on C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ClassicApplet1/scripts/classicapplet1.scr  
ApduTool [v3.0.2]  
    Copyright (c) 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  
    All rights reserved.  
    Use is subject to license terms.  
Opening connection to localhost on port 9025.  
Connected.  
Received ATR = 0x3b 0xf0 0x11 0x00 0xff 0x00   
CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 06, e9, 64, 73, ab, 62, df, Le: 00, SW1: 69, SW2: 99  
run-for-debug:  
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 25 seconds)
```

What is the cause/reason for the crash. Notice: I am new to the java smart cart ecosystem.
What's up with `Off Card Installer sending create request`

Comment: Are you sure the problem is caused by the line with RandomData? Did you try installing your applet without it?

Comment: yes, I stepped through and it fails at the line with the above error message. I am trying to generate a random key.

Comment: What about `RandomData.ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM`?

Comment: Yes, this code works - But why does the other fails?
I need secure random in order to generate a secure key, don't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your card probably does not support `RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM`.

To prove it, try surrounding the line with a try-catch block like this:

```
try {
    RandomData.getInstance(RandomData.ALG_SECURE_RANDOM);
} catch(CryptoException e) {
    if (e.getReason() != CryptoException.NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM) {
         throw e;
    }
}
```

You will have to use `RandomData.ALG_PSEUDO_RANDOM` instead. Unfortunately, the security of this algorithm is not guaranteed, so you must be very careful and you should contact your card vendor.

Comment: I am not deploying it on a card yet. All I have done was writing some code in netbeeans ice using a java card applet project with version 3. How can I tell, if this method is supported. Shouldn't it be simulatable on the PC?

Comment: I tried the try/catch block and the exception thrown is a NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM exception. But I am currently emulating on my laptop. Why is it thrown anyway?

Comment: @DanielHitzel Simulators also does not implement all the algorithms. It seems that this answer is correct, if so, please mark it.

Comment: @DanielHitzel Yes, emulators usually emulate a particular card type and they do not allow you to use algorithms, which the particular card type does not support. You may find interesting this "card type - algorithm" overview: http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvenda/jcsupport.html